# How to format my bound wpf datagrid text column to not show new DateTimes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetime, datagrid

I have a column that is bound to a property of my object. The property, LastRunDate, is a Datetime. On default/start, it displays a date along the lines of of 1/1/1 12:00 AM.

Is there a way in my XAML to format my date where if I have a date of this value, to instead show a string of "None" or even a blank? Is there a way I can put this into my string format?

Here's the XAML right now:

```
       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SourceServerName}" Header="Server Source" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SourceDataBaseName}" Header="Database" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastRunTime, StringFormat={}\{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm\}}" Header="Last Run Time" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: If switching to a nullable `DateTime?` does not work for you, I would recommend an `IValueConverter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converter:

```
class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            var test = (DateTime)value;
            if (test == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                return "None";
            }
            var date = test.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
            return (date);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <stackOverflow:DateTimeConverter x:Key="DateTimeConverter"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastRunTime, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}" Header="Last Run Time" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You may want to implement the `ConvertBack` method to parse `"None"` as `DateTime.MinValue` if you go this route so you don't attempt to store the string `"None"` in a DateTime object.

Comment: That would only be required if the DataGrid would be editable, allowing the UI to update the source property.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of `LastRunDate` to `Datetime?`. Then use this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastRunTime, TargetNullValue=None,
                     StringFormat={}\{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm\}}" Header="Last Run Time" />
```

Since your property isn't initialized on start (i.e. it is `null`), you will see "None".

Comment: Thanks Hamlet. However, I tried it and still saw a string of the date. From my understanding (I could be wrong), DateTime isn't ever actually "null", but a default minvalue when created on new. LastRunTime is a DateTime type already.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't change the type of `LastRunTime`?

Comment: No I mean to say that it's always been the DateTime type.

Comment: Can you show your model and how do you initialize it?